# Create a responsive web app with Django or jQueryMobile?

Tags: python, django, responsive-design

I have a bigger project to handle, so this is what I want to do:

I have a **Server** with an `MySQL` database and `Apache` webserver running on. I save some machine information data in the database and want to create a web app to see, e. g. if the machine is running.

The web app should be designed **responsive**, i. e. changing design in accordance to the screen resolution of the current used device. This is important because the app will be used from smartphones and tablets mainly, but should also work on a normal pc.

I wrote a `Python` programm for my machine to get the data, and another `Python` programm on my server receiving information and saving in the database.
So my job now is to create the "responsive website" for my smartphone etc.
Then I want to broadcast this with my webserver.

Another Point is, that the web app should be **build dynamically**.
If I add another machine to my database, it should appear on my web app to be clickable and then show the related information.

First I thought about doing this in `HTML5` and `CSS3`, with the use of `jQueryMobile`.
But I never used `javascript`. I'm just experienced in the "old" `HTML` and `CSS`.

Is `Django` a better choice, since I'm quite experienced in `Python`?
Or do I need both perhaps?
I haven't worked with any webframework yet, please help me choosing.
Or do I need one at all?

Comment: The frontend design of the application has very little to do with the backend server. You will need both a backend application (django) as well as a frontend library or application. Eitherway, SO isn't the place to get recommendations for libraries or tools

Comment: you can use Django as your backend server and use twitter bootstrap or zurb foundation for making responsive web as your frontend

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony thanks, where can I get better information on how to build this app? Is there a book or website you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution now is as follows:
I will use the `bottle` microframework for generating serverside dynamic html-pages on request.
This will cause me to reload the page everytime I want to see new machine information, but for now it is enough for me.

Later I can add `AJAX` for live monitoring (I know this is `javascript`, I think I have to learn it anyway.)

Thanks for your solutions though.

Comment: Shouldn't accept your own answer when it is just opinion based.  Other people offered suggestions about how to accomplish your goal.  You should accept one of those.  And edit your post with what you decided.

Comment: What do you mean by opinion based? None of the only solution proposed solved his problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your server layer is OK for getting server informations and storing informations in database. Done with python.

And now, if I can resume, you need :

1. a reponsive web client
2. notification features
3. dynamically able to display new set for html elements

Based on this, I doubt in the fact that you will find a complete already packaged solution. Django should have this kind of features but it is not my favorite approach for such custom requirements.

If I have to do this I would use :

1. NodeJS for serverside code managing notifications
2. AngularJS for clientside managing client (!) and clean dynamic DOM manipulation with directives.
3. CSS Framework like Foundation or Bootstrap where responsive is native

What I would do is :

Init Phase

1. install nodejs and yeoman
2. initialize an angular app
3. write basic nodeJS server with a basic HTTP service
4. test your HTTP service with curl & your app with chrome or FF

Integration Phase

1. write basic angular HTTP call to this service
2. add communication between Node and Python (See
   [Combining node.js and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775351/combining-node-js-and-python)
   or something like this)

Client & Look and feel phase

1. add CSS framework for responsive and use it (navbar, table...)
2. look at Angular directives, develop a directive for adding new DOM elements

Finish / Clean your code and rollout

Comment: This is a terrible suggestion. Why complicate the server with node.js and the frontend with angular when he has already mentioned he is not familiar with javascript.

Comment: My point was trying to propose solutions for precisly responding to the mobile notication requirement (nodejs is strong for this) and a simple way to add GUI elements (new servers). But I agree with you in that depending on the context it can be more or less a complicate approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can put Bootstrap too for making responsive website. 
Follow the code below code in your `index.html` in Django template.

```
<html>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
{% block head %}
   :
   :
{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
    .
    .
    .
{% endblock %}

 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```