# Run Python in background of NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js

I'm not sure what I'm trying to do is possible, but I'm trying to write a NodeJS application that needs to call some Python functions, the way I'm going to use Python functions is similar to [How to call Python function from NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-python-function-from-nodejs) by using child_process

If the python script had a few imports that had a slight delay when running the script, if you were calling the python script often surely it would cause problems for the applications running time. Is there a way to get around to constantly keep a child process python call open and then call a function whenever it's needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing specific to Python nor node.js here. If you don't want the overhead of spawning a child process, make the "other" script / application / whatever a long running process and use any kind of [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: Here is a good article / example for Node/Python and when you don't want to spawn a child process:  https://ianhinsdale.com/post/communicating-between-nodejs-and-python/