# Raspberry: nodejs http-server execute script server side

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have a raspberry with nodejs + (npm) http-server installation. I would like to controlo gpio port from a web page. 
I obtained that, with express framework and GET operations on specific URL. Now I would like to control gpio from a web page, serverd by http-server, where links control specific gpio pin.
Can I execute a javascript server side to control rpi-gpio library? Or I have to deploy a REST API server with express framework?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend reading this: [How to call a Python function from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-a-python-function-from-node-js)

You can make a child process that can be fired upon from the node server into python (which can interact with the gpio if I remember correctly) or another language