# Can I pass a list of lists from Node to python easily?

Tags: python, node.js, command-line-interface, sys

I know there is some issues with passing in more complicated data structures, such as a list of lists, to a python script via the CLI.

I was wondering if running a python script from node code had any of these same issues.

Basically, say I have the following code in a node app:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["path/to/script.py", arg1, arg2, arg3]);
```

[Question the above code is from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-a-python-function-from-node-js)

Suppose that arg1 and arg2 are lists of lists in the node app. And suppose arg3 is a double.

The corresponding code in my script.py file that is meant to parse and receive these arguments into variables looks like so:

```
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    oc = sys.argv[1]
    nc = sys.argv[2]
    r = sys.argv[3]
```

Will oc and nc here be lists of lists in python? Or does something else need to be done to get this working?

Comment: No, they will always be `str` objects. You could trivially check for yourself . Why don't you consider a text-based serialization format like JSON?

Comment: would it work if arg1 and arg2 were JSON objects when node passes them in?

Comment: No, it won't. **They will always be `str` objects**. Again, this is easily verifiable. But JSON is a data transfer format. That is what it's for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to pass complex structures is to serialize it first in some common data format, such as JSON:

```js
const myList = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const python = spawn('python',["script.py", JSON.stringify(myList)]);
```

And deserialize on callee side:

```py
import sys, json

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_list = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
```

But, instead of passing serialized params as callee arguments, better use `stdout` and `stdin` streams for interchanging data larger than a few hundreds of bytes:

```js
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

const python = spawn('python', ["script.py"]);
const buffers = [];

python.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => buffers.push(chunk));
python.stdout.on('end', () => {
    const result = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(buffers));
    console.log('Python process exited, result:', result);
});

python.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(["foo", "bar", "baz"]));
python.stdin.end()
```

And accept it from `sys.stdin` via `json.load`, which takes streams instead of strings:

```py
import sys, json

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_list = json.load(sys.stdin)
    json.dump(my_list, sys.stdout)
```

Comment: Thanks! quick question. How would i pass multiple different vars that are lists using the stdout and stdin streams you demonstrate as the better way to do this? This example only shows how to pass one list in.

Comment: @mark_maker, the same way, just wrapping all variables you need to pass in js object:
`const passedVars = { arg1, arg2, myList }; python.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(passedVars))`. On python side, such clause will be unwrapped in `dict` instance with corresponding fields:
`data = json.load(sys.stdin)  # data['arg1'], data['arg2'], data['myList']`

Comment: @mark_maker or you can pass it as array instead of object, and deconstruct it directly into variables:
`python.stdin.write(JSON.stringify([arg1, arg2, myList]))`
...
`arg1, arg2, myList = json.load(sys.stdin)`.
But in that case ordering of deconstructed variables on python side should correspond to order of items in the array on JS side, so I recommend to stick to the first approach with object/dict instances marshalling and depend on names instead.

Comment: how to send python list to node js then?

Comment: @LukAron the example above was updated with bi-directional communication. Please note that node should explicitly pass EOF to python stdin stream (`python.stdin.end()`), otherwise python process would be stuck indefinitely waiting for more data to come.

In complex cases you may want to use other approaches like unix socket communications or full-featured IPCs