# How to run python program with node js

Tags: python, node.js, express

I have an Express Node.js application, but I want to run a machine learning python codw with a following command.

I already find some online solutions to run python machine learning code.With this stackoverflow link
[How to call a Python function from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-a-python-function-from-node-js)

But with this solution I just run run a python code.

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
      var process = spawn('python', ["./my_script.py"]);
      process.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        res.send(data.toString());
      })
```

With this code I just run a code `python hello.py` .But I want to run a code with following commands `python test.py --model dataset/test.model --image s.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell)

```
import {PythonShell} from 'python-shell';

const options = {
            args: [
                '--image',
                's.jpg'
            ]
        };

PythonShell.run('script.py', options, (err, results) => {
  // your code 
});
```

If you want to use **spawn** you can do somthing like this:

```
const args = ['script.py', '--image', 's.jpg'];
const process = spawn('python', args);
```