# How to make python script server side

Tags: javascript, python, html, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to make my raspberry PI host a website for control of a system on my house but can't run server side Python

I've tried this in Javascript:

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';
exec("sudo python /home/pi/Light.py");
```

It's supposed to run Light.py server side because it contains GPIO instructions for the pi but the PI just sits there doing nothing

Comment: Can this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-a-python-function-from-node-js

Answer (score 3):

Javascript's `exec()` is not for running anything server side, Python or otherwise.

Probably the easiest way to achieve what you're looking for would be to use a simple Python web framework, such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). You could expose a simple HTTP endpoint doing whatever you need doing, and hit that from Javascript.

Comment: How and where is this Javascript being run? `child_process` looks like a node thing, which would also run server side. How's it being triggered? What happens if you SSH onto your Pi and run `sudo python /home/pi/Light.py`?

Comment: It simply flickers a light for now on testing

Comment: Sorry, I need to be more specific. This Javascript code - where does it run, on your Pi, or on a client machine? How is it triggered? (What it does is unimportant from the point of view of solving your problem.)

Comment: And what happens if you SSH onto your Pi and run `sudo python /home/pi/Light.py`?