# Child_Processes calling function from javascript node js to python breaking with imports

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, child-process

I am using `node js` for my application as well as `react.`

I am trying to use `child_process` to call a python function from my node js code, using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-a-python-function-from-node-js) to guide me. It seems pretty straightforward, until I realized that the `child_process` was used to call a python script, not a main method with functions.

I am relatively new to Python, so forgive me if I mix up terminology here and there. Here is a very basic version of my python file below:

```
import sys
# other imports 

def __main__():
     one = function_one()
     two = function_two()
     arr = [one, two]
     print(arr)
     sys.stdout.flush()

def function_one():
     # do stuff, pretend it returns 'hello'
def function_two():
     # do stuff, pretend it returns 'world'

if __name__ == '__main__':
     __main__()
```

The end result should be `['hello', 'world']`, but it seems like I am not getting returned anything. As you can see, I am printing `arr` and flushing it afterwards, so it should work.

The only way I can get it to work is if my file looks like this:

```
import sys
print('hello world')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

As you can see, without the main method or additional functions. **Is there a reason to this or am I just implementing it wrongly? Thanks!**

**EDIT:**

After trying a couple different things, I found out that some of my imports were breaking, such as `pandas` or `seaborn`. It works if I remove those specific imports, even if I'm calling `__main__` through the if statement. Any ideas why?

Comment: Your `__main__` function won't be automatically executed. No matter if you run this script from the CLI, import it in another script, or execute it with Node's `child_process` (which is almost the same thing as executing it from the CLI). You can't call Python functions declared in a .py script directly from a Node.js application without using extra libraries. You can, however, run the whole script as explained in [the post you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-a-python-function-from-node-js). Simply get rid of `__main__` and move the code to the end of the scrip

Comment: @TomaszKasperczyk I removed all the code inside `__main__` to the end of my file. I was still not able to make it work. I even altered my code a little to include `print('test')` then `sys.stdout.flush()` above `one = function_one()` and it didn't print that one either. Do you have another idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my problem was that in my spawn, python was pointing to version `2.7`, not `3.6.` Just alter the spawn to point to `python3.6` and it'll fix the import issues.

Answer (score 0):

You declare a function called `__main__` and then never call it. I think you've mixed things up with a known pattern that prevents code from being executed when a script is imported as a module. The correct implementation of this pattern would look like this:

```
import sys

def myMainFunction(argv):
    # the code here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myMainFunction(sys.argv)
```

`__name__` [is a special variable](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__name__-special-variable-python/) in Python. It is automatically set to `"__main__"` if the script was executed directly. If it was imported, it would hold the module's name instead.

Back to your problem. If you don't plan to import that script as a module, here's a solution I suggested in the comments:

*Node.js:*

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const pythonProcess = spawn('python', ['script.py']);

pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

*Python:*

```
import sys

def function_one():
    return 'hello'
def function_two():
    return 'world'

one = function_one()
two = function_two()
arr = [one, two]
print(arr)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I tried your above code and it didn't work. I figured out what is causing the issue is though, see my edit above for further clarification!