# How to use html and javascript to choose a file and and run it in command line with python3 commands at the click of a button

Tags: javascript, python, html, angular, terminal

So I have been trying to upload a .xlsx file to a html file (Website) and then re-format the .xlsx file to turn it into a database and then finally be able to search through the database.

I have 3 scripting files for this, `validation.py`, `reader.py` and `server.py`. they coexist to run a search database web app.

I use Terminal commands to run them, and I want to automate this process so that I may:

**1.** choose a file and run it with validation (`python3 validation.py -i (chosen file)`)

**2.** read the file (`python3 reader.py -i (chosen file) -o (category of file (i.e. chosen file is phone numbers so category would be numbers)`)

**3.** run (`server.py -m (category of file_model)`)

This opens up a `localhost://8080` file. I want to automate the validation, reader, and server commands, so that I may choose a file and then have the commands occur at the click of a button, and open up my `localhost`.

What might be a good way to do this?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Stack Overflow is about coding questions, but here you're asking about how to run a web server...  You'll have to be more precise about a specific coding question.

Comment: its not a server at all actually, just a web app, i edited the question :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to make an HTML and JavaScript app that achieves two objectives.

1. Display a file picker
2. Run a set of Python commands

I would recommend you use [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) for this. It allows you to create HTML and JavaScript apps that can interact with terminal commands like Python.

Make sure to get [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) installed first to use Electron.

To start you will need the [Electron Quick Start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start). I have linked it on GitHub and you can get it like this.

```
# Clone this repository
git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
# Go into the repository
cd electron-quick-start
# Install dependencies
npm install
```

Within the folder you will find the familiar `index.html` file. To add a file picker to your app use the below HTML. You can read more about it on the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file).

```
<input type="file" id="myFilePicker">
```

In order to have your Python commands run when a file is picked, you can make use of the `preload.js` file included with the Quick Start. This JavaScript can interact with your HTML and also your computer. Replace it's contents with the below code.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('myFilePicker').addEventListener('change', function(event) {

    let filePath = this.files[0].path

    const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
    const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["path/to/script.py", filePath]);

    pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      // You have data from Python
    });

  })
})
```

This JavaScript does the following:

- Waits for the HTML to load
- Listens for the file picker to change
- Gets the path to the file that was chosen
- Runs a python script, passing the file path as a parameter.

The Python script code was used from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-a-python-function-from-node-js). Within the arrow function that says `You have data from Python`, you are free to repeat the Python script code. You can then run your second and third scripts.

You can then run `npm start` in the terminal to launch your new Electron app.