# AWS CLI command not run when executed via npm run command

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-sam-cli

System specification -

```
node version - v10.15.0
npm version - 6.4.1
aws-cli version - aws-cli/1.16.81 Python/3.6.0 Windows/10 botocore/1.12.71
sam-cli version - SAM CLI, version 0.41.0

Running on a windows machine.
```

So I have a node project, which would be deployed to `aws-sam`. I have scripts for `sam-validate`, `prepare`, `package`. But when I run this script via `npm run <package-name>`, commands don't run. For example If I run `npm run package`, I get the following -

```
aws --region <region-name> s3api head-bucket --bucket <bucket-name>
Command not run
Command executed in 0 msec
aws --region <<region-name>> cloudformation package --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket <bucket-name> --output-template-file template-deploy.yaml
Command not run
Command executed in 0 msec
```

But surprisingly If I run those commands from powershell individually, then it works fine. Which made me come to the realization that scripts are okay, as the generated commands do work when I run them individually.

I checked my environment variables. All the things(node path, aws cli path etc.) are there.

**What am I missing here? Simply put the problem is - Do I need to do anything else to run `aws-cli` or `sam-cli` commands through node scripts?**

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with your scripts i think,

Consider writing the script in python like

```
import subprocesses
commandToBeExecutedOnShell='any command'
subprocess.check_call(commandToBeExecutedOnShell, shell=True)
```

You can then either run the scripts from python itself or

create a separate node app which calls python functions

Reference [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-a-python-function-from-node-js)

and then run that node app using `npm run`