# How to Automate the process of reading code, computing it and providing the output on web page to the user?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, frontend, backend, server-side-rendering

I want to automate a process in which a python file is uploaded to a web portal by the user(let's say the code is math formula) ,in the back-end the code in the file is computed through different input values that already exists in the back-end and the outputs of the computation will be returned on web-page of the user.?If this is possible then what will be the approach to do this? If possible can we also provide the graphical representation of the different outputs to the user?Or if not then can anyone provide any resource or references or any help that will help me to solve this problem?

!THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to execute the uploaded Python file by the user you have to spawn a Python process from your backend server and pass it the name of file. Pass the arguments the the script also here. Save the output on your server and expose it to the user via a HTTP request.

Comment: can you provide me any specific tutorials or article from which i can understand the whole process of doing it if possible.... please

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Comment: i want that all the computation should be done in python and i their any means through which i can contact you?

Comment: There is chat feature on stack overflow

Comment: I'm not able use it..may be due to less count of reputation anyways... please guide me with some tutorials or article from where i can learn in details

Comment: Oh could you upvote it I mean, you are a new member

Comment: Which backend technology do you use?

Comment: i want to do computation in python

Comment: Yeah... I mean which tech you use for the web server?

Comment: i will use node.js

Comment: See this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-a-python-function-from-node-js

Comment: and what if i have to use marionettejs and backbonejs?

Comment: Just don’t do it

Comment: befor I thought i should make have to make From scratch so i could hai use any web server bt now i get to know that i have to work with marionette and backbonejs

Comment: No that’s false information you don’t need to use marionette (never ever heard of it lol) or backbonejs

Comment:  web portal in which i have to integrate the python functioning (asked above in my question ) should be integrated with  the website whose front end and server is already setup in marionette and backbonejs

Comment: Well those are frontend frameworks and your question was about backend. Read my answer again

Comment: Or post a new question and I’ll answer you there