# Is there a way to use tensorflow with node js?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, tensorflow, machine-learning

1.I want to know if its possible to use tensorflow(using python) in the browser or in a node js server.

2.Is there a way to use tensorflow in vs code. If not, does tensorflow.js have all the basic functions as tensorflow(python)?

3.Can I learn tensorflow and implement the same knowledge in the tensorflow.js api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tensorflow.js is the same python tensorflow library but modified to fit js code. The API should be relatively similar. It can be downloaded as a node module via npm or as a plugin via cdn. For more information, see the following link:https://www.tensorflow.org/js.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely https://www.tensorflow.org/js! But if you want to use the Python API but access it through NodeJs you might want to have a look at [How to call a Python function from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-a-python-function-from-node-js).
But I think using the NodeJS API directly is the better way here.