# How to send data from node to python

Tags: python, node.js, web

i can run python script through spawn but i am unable to send node object to python script and access that object in python.Can anybody explain me how to send node object to python and how to used that object in python.
Thanks

Comment: Via network calls, or other IPC mechanisms depending on your environment.

Comment: The easiest way seems to be serializing it to JSON and pushing it through stdin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a Python function from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-a-python-function-from-node-js)