# A Promise with child_process running a Python script in Node.js - Process exits before all data

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, es6-promise, child-process

I'm trying to get sublist3r to run in a node app.  It runs, however, it only shows the banner and then exits out in about 5 seconds. The script is supposed to reach out to the web and takes about 30 seconds to run.  If I don't use a promise, it will work just fine.  Does it have something to do with `pyrog.stdout.on('data')` not waiting before it outputs?    I've read around and tried `'end'` with no luck.

Tried everything on [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-a-python-function-from-node-js) if it didn't involve editing python script (I don't think I should need to ?!)

Also read the [Node.js Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) but it doesn't mention using promises with spawn, and I believe that's what I need to use for running a Python script.

[sublist3r screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwDjM.png)

Am I using Promises wrong?

Any help is much appreciated

Edit: Added await to runPy, verified same issue.  Have also tried making it a variable, `let test = await runPy ...` with no success

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

let runPy = new Promise((success, nosuccess) => {
    const {spawn} = require('child_process')
    const pyprog = spawn('python',['/path/to/sublist3r.py', '-d', 'domain.com'] )

    pyprog.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        success(data)
    })

    pyprog.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        nosuccess(data)
    })

    pyprog.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`child process ended with ${code}`);
    })
})


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {

    // EDIT:  Added await and verified same issue.
    await runPy.then(fromRunPy => {
        console.log(fromRunPy.toString());
    })

    // It works fine below, but I want a promise for no other reason that I can't get it to work...
    // const { spawn } = require('child_process');
    // const pyProg = spawn('python', ['/home/wayne/BugHunterJS/controllers/Sublist3r/sublist3r.py', '-d', req.body.domain]);
    
    // console.log('inside post');
    // pyProg.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    //     let sublist3rData = data.toString();
    //     console.log(sublist3rData);
    // });

  });

module.exports = router
```

Comment: You're missing `await` before `runPy.then`

Comment: I'll update when i get to computer. I've tried that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Not shortly after I asked, I found a solution if anyone is looking.  I'm still not really sure how it works, got to figure that out later.  I think pushing it to the array is the key.

```
const {
    spawn
} = require('child_process')
const logOutput = (name) => (data) => console.log(`[${name}] ${data}`)


function run() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const process = spawn('python', ['/path/sublist3r.py', '-d', 'domain.com']);

        const out = []
        process.stdout.on(
            'data',
            (data) => {
                out.push(data.toString());
                logOutput('stdout')(data);
            }
        );

        const err = []
        process.stderr.on(
            'data',
            (data) => {
                err.push(data.toString());
                logOutput('stderr')(data);
            }
        );

        process.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
            logOutput('exit')(`${code} (${signal})`)
            if (code === 0) {
                resolve(out);
            } else {
                reject(new Error(err.join('\n')))
            }
        });
    });
}

(async () => {
    try {
        const output = await run()
        logOutput('main')(output)
        process.exit(0)
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error during script execution ', e.stack);
        process.exit(1);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question. This worked for me with my python script running in node js