# Running python from args in nodejs [discord.js]

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to run python commmands from nodejs in such a way:

user input: print(69)
bot process user input and execute command
bot sends results into chat

i have taken this code and modify myself to args.join (' ')

```
 let options = {
                mode: 'text',
                pythonPath: 'C:/Python39/python.exe',
                pythonOptions: ['-u'], // get print results in real-time
                args: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
            };


            PythonShell.run(args.join(' '), options, function (err, results) {
                if (err) throw err;
                // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
                message.channel.send('results: %j', results);
            });
```

and somehow pythonshell is trying to draw commands from a file other then a argument.

```
PythonShellError: C:/Python39/python.exe: can't open file 'C:\bot096\memu stable\print(69)': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

    at PythonShell.parseError (C:\bot096\memu stable\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:269:21)
    at terminateIfNeeded (C:\bot096\memu stable\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:144:32)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\bot096\memu stable\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:118:17)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:388:22)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1305:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21) {
  executable: 'C:/Python39/python.exe',
  options: [ '-u' ],
  script: 'print(69)',
  args: [ 'value1', 'value2', 'value3' ],
  exitCode: 2
}
```

so i am out of ideas how to actually make it draw from input not from a file??

fetched source:

https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell

also looked at these

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/run-python-script-using-pythonshell-from-node-js/

[How to call a Python function from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-a-python-function-from-node-js)

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/286/how-to-execute-a-python-script-and-retrieve-output-data-and-errors-in-node-js

---

if im wrong, correct me. Im here to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry i have managed to produce an result by changing options from -u to -c.