# How to call a Flask Python function and use it using NestJS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, flask, nestjs

I have a NodeJS application using NestJS as its framework. My goal is to simply call a function from Flask Python using NestJS that runs on the same server together. I already attempted to do the one with the similar requirement but using Express instead of NestJS, but I had some challenges that ultimately didn't work for me at all. Is there a way for me to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-a-python-function-from-node-js your answer is here believe

Comment: @Sinakzlca this is one of the few things I did but didn't work. Probably because it's for Express and Im using NestJS. Or probably im doing something wrong.

Comment: NestJS is a wrapper around Express, so that wouldn't be the case, and both Express and NestJS are NodeJS frameworks, so the underlying language and code runner should be the same