# How to use model with TFIdVectorizer in react webapp

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, machine-learning, nlp

I created this book recommendation model by watching tutorials on youtube and searching articles online,now I want to use it for my react webapp. I have used TfidVectorizer to create a cosine similarity matrix to recommend books but I have no idea how to take that model and use it on my react webapp which is made using node.js and react.js.

```
def get_recommendations(book_title, cosine_sim=cosine_sim):
    # Get the index of the movie that matches the title
    idx = indices[book_title]
    
    # Similarity scores
    similarity_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[idx]))

    # Sort the books based on the similarity scores
    similarity_scores = sorted(similarity_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    # Get the scores of the six most similar books
    similarity_scores =  similarity_scores[1:6]

    # Get the book indices
    book_indices = [i[0] for i in similarity_scores]

    # Return the top 5 most similar books
    return book_summary['book_title'].iloc[book_indices]
```

This is the code for the recommendation function and I want to use this in my webapp

Comment: Do you mean you're not sure where/how to actually place the model in the app so it can be used at runtime?

Comment: Yes, the model is mostly in python and webapp is in react and node.js, so I don't know how to integrate the model with my webapp

Comment: Ok, maybe the answers to this question may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-a-python-function-from-node-js