# Is there anything similar to PyAutoGUI for NodeJS that can try to locate an image inside a screen capture?

Tags: node.js, pyautogui, robotjs

I am trying to code a bot to automate some tasks on a videogame with JS and Node, so far I've been using RobotJS. The problem I'm facing is that I need to find something on the screen as it moves from time to time to then click on it. Something similar to PyAutoGUI `locateOnScreen()` function.

It needs to use AI to have some tolerance too, as the image will not be exactly the same from time to time, though it's almost the same so I think any basic AI for image recognition would detect it fine.

Does anyone have an idea on what to use for this specific case?

Comment: You could invoke a python script from NodeJS using a child process, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-a-python-function-from-node-js

Comment: @KyleRifqi In this case it doesn't make much sense as it is a pretty small bot and I could just code it in Python then, but I want to know if there are any NodeJS libraries similar to PyAutoGUI with image recognition as I haven't been able to find one. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this package called `node-moving-things-tracker`. I have been using it reliably for a while. It is being actively maintained. Data outputs are well-organized and interpretable. There are a few examples here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-moving-things-tracker

Comment: Thanks! I also want to add that I found a package similar to pyautogui called Nut.js https://nutjs.dev/ though it doesn't work as good as pyautogui, I'll take a look at yours and will mark this question as solved.