# how to include python files in node js build

Tags: python, node.js, npm, npm-build

I'm stumped here...

I have a node server that calls to a python file for some quick data processing using the `spawn` approach ([How to call a Python function from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-a-python-function-from-node-js))
...and I got it working from the npm CLI.

The issue now is, when actually running the server, the `.py` file is not being included in the build. So `__dirname` at runtime is based within the `dist` folder, and running `npm build` never copies the `.py` file into the `dist` folder.

There's got to be a way to include the python file, right?
I tried editing `package.json`'s `files` field with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a script to `package.json` that does the copy, and including it as part of the `build` script:

```
...
"build": "nest build && npm run cp:py",
"cp:py": "cp -n src/python/*.py dist/python"
...
```

Comment: It seems like you have a workaround working. Use this for now.