# How would I use the M.E.A.N. Stack with a Python script backend where the python script is in a container?

Tags: python, docker, containers, mean-stack, microservices

So I am in the process of writing a web app with the full M.E.A.N. stack and know how to work with both the front end and the back end.  My only problem is incorporating things outside of M.E.A.N.  As an example, I am going to be running a Python script as the algorithmic back end for the web app (mainly due to necessity of specific libraries) where that Python script will be inside of a docker container.  What would be the most optimal way to connect to and run said Python code through M.E.A.N.?

Comment: See this question on communicating between Node.js and Python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775351/combining-node-js-and-python

Answer (score 0):

Getting started with the MEAN stack might seem very daunting at first. You might think that there is too much new technology to learn.  The truth is that you really only need to know “Javascript.” That’s right, MEAN is simply a javascript web development stack.

So, how do you actually get started developing on the MEAN stack?

The first step is to set up a project structure. I’ve found the following structure to make the most sense:

controllers/ db/ package.json server.js public/

This structure lets you keep the entire stack in a single project. Your AngularJS front end can go into the public folder while all your Express API logic goes into controller and your MongoDB collections and logic go into the db folder.

Now that you’ve set up a general project structure, you need to initialize your public folder as  an Angular project. It is best to do this using a tool called Yeoman.

Yeoman is a toolkit that makes it easy for you to get started with a variety of Javascript frameworks and other web frameworks like Bootstrap and foundation. You can learn more about Yeoman at Yeoman.io.

You can read more about the M.E.A.N. stack here and how to get started: http://www.citizentekk.com/mean-stack-tutorial-how-to-build-loosely-coupled-scalable-web-apps-nodejs-angularjs-applications/