# Which is the easiest way to allow comunication between NodeJS and a Python script

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, node.js

I would like to know which is the easiest way to send an array of values **from JS to a Python Script** and then, after some operations, send back **from Python to JS** the modified array and print it with console.log(array) to check the changes.

I am working with node js and my server in running on http://localhost:1234

Thank you in advance

Comment: Would this work? https://www.ivarprudnikov.com/nodejs-server-running-python-scripts/

Comment: There are many ways: Nodejs can execute a Python script via [subprocess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html), you could use a database and/or some pub/sub mechanisms (like Redis pub/sub). Run the Python script within a webserver and let node.js make AJAX call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining node.js and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775351/combining-node-js-and-python)